# Configure Apache2 for Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu

I use ubuntu server and I install apache2.

I write at laravel.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

then I restart Apache2.
and wont work...

I also at `/html` folder create .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

also:
 at /pubic folder I add .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
            Options -MultiViews
        </IfModule>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

        # Handle Front Controller...
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

and now view folder work... so when I go at: `/auth/login` everything is fine I see DOMhtml but when I try to click on login after that show me 500 error:
[image]

How I can solve my problem? What is a problem with Apache2 ? How to properly configured them?

Comment: check resolve you domine. and replace server name `ServerName localhost` to `ServerName yourdomain.com`.

Comment: I try but not work...

Comment: apache2 is start? try `ping yourdomain.com` for check ip resolved

Comment: I also update php version to 5.6.* but dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change `.htaccess`. Try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName netracuni.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/public>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, set write permissions on `storage` directory:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

Restart Apache.

http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

If id doens't work, what error does it return?

Comment: Check your logs. What are they syaing? Did you set write permissions to a `storage` directory and all it's contents? If not, do a `chmod -R 775 storage`

Comment: So, set it to 775 or 777 with -R (recursive).

Comment: storage was a problem, but how permison can make a such a big problme